# Make a Condition Before Display Published Post in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Can any body help Me?

How can I redirect users to a custom not found page if the request page is not found and also the searched post name starts with "news" word.

So if the requested not found slug starts with "news" like [www.domain.com/news-blog-item](http://www.domain.com/news-blog-item) then It should redirect to a specific page where I can show different content.

if the requested not found slug starts with any word other than "news" like [www.domain.com/test-blog-item](http://www.domain.com/test-blog-item) then It should redirect to the default not found page.

Comment: You can display everything on single.php
If you setup the Template Hierarchy correctly this should work automatically on wordpress.
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Comment: Thanks. No. I want to do it with some code. I just confused, where to put the condition code.

Comment: you can write custom code in functions.php

Comment: So help me please..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to display custom content for a not found post if the slug starts with "news", you need to redirect the user to a different page and show the content there.

Add the below code in the functions.php Make sure you have created that custom page before doing this redirect

```
    function rf_custom_redirect() {
    $page_slug = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$link_array = explode('/',$page_slug);
$page = end($link_array);
    $firstword = strtok($page, "-");
if( is_404() && $firstword == "news"){
//Code you want to execute if the first word is news
wp_redirect( home_url( '/custom-page/' ) );
        exit();
        }
else
{
//Code you want to execute if the first word is not news
}
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'rf_custom_redirect' );
```

Below code is to display specific content in single.php if blog post slug starts with news.

First, You need to get the POST SLUG/URL in the single.php file(Single Blog Post template). For that, use the below code.

```
global $post;
$page_slug = $post->post_name;
```

There is a string function (strtok) in PHP which can be used to split a string into smaller strings (tokens) based on separator. In our case, the separator would be hypen(-).

We can get the first word of the page slug using the code below.

```
$firstword = strtok($page_slug, "-");
```

Then you just check if the $firstword is "news" using a simple IF condition.

```
if($firstword == "news")
{
//Code you want to execute if the first word is news
}
else
{
//Code you want to execute if the first word is not news
}
```

Comment: I've tried, when there are "news" character in the slug, but it still redirect to 404 page,

Comment: Yes, it still redirected to 404 error page, because the slug domain.com/news-anything is not in database. I want, it can displayed what i want to show up.

Comment: Do you mean, You want to change the content of the 404 not found page if the slug has "news" word in it?

Comment: No. i don't want to change the content of the 404 page, i just want when there is a "news" character in the slug, it will display what i want to show in single.php

Comment: and no redirect to 404 page. although the slug:domain.com/news-anything is not in the database

Comment: So, you want to display a content on single.php itself without redirecting to 404 page if the slug has news word?

Comment: so I think, there is a function before, whose job is to check a slug, whether it is in the database. if there is then display it as a post, if not then switch to page 404. Well, in this section I want to change, if slug not in database, then check again, if there is "news" in the slug, then don't redirect to page 404

Comment: If you don't want to redirect to 404 then you have to redirect them to a different page so you can show them desired content. Is that okay?

Comment: YES, but where I can write the code? to redirect if a slug have "news" character to different page.